# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to SpringMVC and Hibernate. When I run my prgm I m getting the error as SQLGrammarException and table not exists. But table is there in the DB.

My Controller

```
@Controller
public class ExamController {
@Autowired
private ExamDAO daoObj;
   @RequestMapping(value="/submitForm.do",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView SubmitForm(@RequestParam("studCon")int Contact,
      @RequestParam("studName")String Name, @RequestParam("studpwd") String password)
 {

 ExamModel modObj = new ExamModel();

   modObj.setStudCon(Contact);
   modObj.setStudName(Name);
   modObj.setStudpwd(password);

         daoObj.save(modObj);
 ModelAndView mvcObj=new ModelAndView("Result");
 return mvcObj;
}}
```

DAO

```
  @Repository 
  @Transactional
  public class ExamDAO {
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessFac;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<String[]> getAllItem()
    {
          Criteria c =sessFac.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ExamModel.class);
                         );
           return c.list();
          }
public int save(ExamModel ge)
  {

 return (Integer) sessFac.getCurrentSession().save(ge);
 }}
```

Model

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "exam")

  public class ExamModel implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -723583058586873479L;  
  @Id
  @Column(name="stud_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int studId;

  @Column(name="stud_name")
  private String studName;

  @Column(name="phone")
  private int studCon;

  @Column(name="pwd")
  private String studpwd;

  public int getStudId() {
    return studId;
  }

  public void setStudId(int studId) {
    this.studId = studId;
  }

  public String getStudName() {
    return studName;
}

public void setStudName(String studName) {
    this.studName = studName;
}

public int getStudCon() {
    return studCon;
}

public void setStudCon(int studCon) {
    this.studCon = studCon;
}

public String getStudpwd() {
    return studpwd;
}

public void setStudpwd(String studpwd) {
    this.studpwd = studpwd;
}
}
```

Can you please help me to get out of this error.
The error says it couldnot insert as there is SQLException.

Comment: It could be wrong DB settings. Which DB do you use? Check all the params and access permissions for the user you use to login.

Comment: Add the full stacktrace.

Comment: MYSQL..SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/ExamFirst] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.model.ExamModel]] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.exam' doesn't exist

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right database connection configured? i.e. are you connecting to the right database?

Comment: Yes...its through dispatcher-servlet rt we r connectiong to the DB???

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty clear:

```
Table 'test.exam' doesn't exist
```

You have to create the table `exam`.

Comment: And your application connects to the same DB aus you have created the table? And you have created the table in db `test`?

Comment: Yes..'exam' table in 'test' db

Comment: @Sims Can you show the database connection configuration?

Comment: <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
   p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   p:url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/test" 
   p:username="user"
   p:password=" l"/>
</beans>

Comment: Can you connect manually to the DB and check the existence of the table by using the ipaddress `192.168.1.2`?

Comment: @Sims can you add the ddl of the table? using `desc exam`

Comment: execute the statement on mysql console, copy it and add it to yout question using the edit function.

Comment: @Sims Why you can not do that?

Comment: Go to your mysql console there you have to enter the command: `use test`<ENTER> than `DESC exam`<ENTER> and the result of this you should copy from the mysql console to your  SQ Question.

Comment: stud_id int(11) NO PRI  auto_increment
stud_name varchar(45) YES   
phone int(11) YES   
pwd varchar(45) YES